# English mixed Chinese: how to express this string in regular expression?

Tags: notepad++

```
(note1 (note1 车辆))
      (note2
```

Note: "(note2" is in a new line, with some spaces in between.

Comment: What do you mean "express in regex"? What do you want to match?

Comment: I meant how to search for such a string in notepad++ using regular expression.  Thanks!

Comment: Okay, You need to show some patterns of the string. Is it always gonna be this exact string? What can change? For example, how many Chinese characters will there be? Is it always 2? Is it always 车辆? What are note1 and note2? You provided so little information.